# Writing to SMB share from Mac kills network on Mac

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mac, network-shares, samba

I have an older server running Ubuntu where I have a few SMB shares. I also have a Mac. I have previously been using my SMB shares from my Mac without any problems.

Recently I had to reinstall Ubuntu on the server and while almost everything is up and running again I have some problems with my SMB shares.

Whenever I try to write to the SMB shares from my Mac the network on my Mac slows to the point where it almost dies.

I can read from them perfectly fine, and copy a file from the server to one of the shared folders on the server without problems. But whenever I try to copy something from my Mac it fails horribly.

I have tried just simple copy paste and using SFTP as well.

So something tells me it had nothing to do with my server, but something to do with my Mac.

I have read quite a few posts by now, which suggested checking stuff like the SMB version via `smbutil` and disabling delayed TCP acks but so far nothing has helped.

I am not even sure what to look for/where to start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of macOS exactly? Does the problem happen on macOS v10.14.4? Have you looked at the system logs and other logs on the Mac to look for clues? Have you run `top` or Activity Monitor to look for clues?

Comment: Also, what's the network connection between them? Wi-Fi (which type, what access point, etc), ethernet (what speed, switch, cables, etc), some combination of them or something else, ...

Comment: @Spiff macos 10.14.4. not sure which logs to look at?
Looking at top and activity monitor doesnt really reveal anything. It is like nothing is happening, see: https://imgur.com/swXRDe6

Comment: @Gordon Davisson Ethernet, 1g. I have used this for a long time without any problems, and if I download something from the web directly to each machine I easily get proper speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tiny bit of progress in the sense that I figured out it doesnt matter which protocol we are talking about. I have tested with both ftp, sftp, scp and none of it works. I have also tested from different computers and it is the same across. I cannot write to the folders from any other computer, but it works fine from itself.